# The solutions of $(z-i)^n+(z+i)^n=z^n$ are real.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I have to prove that the polynomial
$$(z-i)^n+(z+i)^n=z^n $$
has only real solutions. 
The equation is equivalent to
$$ 2(z^n-C_n^2z^{n-2}+C_n^4z^{n-4}-...)=z^n .$$

Comment: what is $x$? Real part of $z$ maybe?

Comment: I’ve somehow doubts that the two senseful answers (*SomeStrangeUser* and *Jyrki Lahtonen*) are complete proofs. Both use the same central argument:  $(x_0-i)^n=\overline{(x_0+i)^n }$ and  $(1+ix)^n=\overline{(1-ix)^n }$ - But for $x_0$ and $x$ not real it can be different. You have accepted the answer and therefore the question: Could you kindly tell me where you have seen the central criterion so that the central argument is true ? Thank you! :-)

Comment: In the answer of SomeStrangeUser $x_0$ is a real (!) solution of h(x)=g(x), by which is proven that is a solution of $(z-i)^n+(z+i)^n=z^n$. Accordingly with the answer of Jyrki Lahtonen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Maybe I think wrong (and I have no intention of protracting the discussion unnecessarily), but I still get the impression that the logic here is twisted. Where is the argument, that $(x_0-i)^n=\overline{(x_0+i)^n}$ ? Of course the construction of *SomeStrangeUser* is interesting how to get $x_0^n$ . But he only gets this result because he assumes $(x_0-i)^n=\overline{(x_0+i)^n}$ first. I have the impression that he shows something that he already uses as a prerequisite.

Comment: @user90369 $\overline{(x_0+i)^n}=(x_0-i)^n$ is correct because $x_0$ is real **by definition** ($x_0$ is defined to be any of the **real** solutions to $g(x)=h(x)$).

Comment: My interpretion of what I understand now: (1) It's shown, that if $z=x_0$ real, then your equation holds. (2) There are *n* real solutions and therefore your equation cannot have more because your equation is of degree *n*. Right ?

Comment: I suggest we continue this discussion in the chat. See: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50159/zinz-inzn

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define:
$$
g(x) := \cos\left(n\cdot\arccos\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)
$$
We claim that we can partition $\mathbb{R}$ into $n$ intervals, where in each interval $g$ continuously moves between the values $-1$ and $1$. To show this, let $f(x):=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$. Note that $f$ increases from $-1$ to $1$ as $x$ goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. This means that $n\cdot\arccos\left(f(x)\right)$ decreases from $n\pi$ to $0$, as as $x$ goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, which proves our claim.

Next, define:
$$
h(x) := \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)^{n}
$$
We note that $-\frac{1}{2}\lt h\lt \frac{1}{2}$ for all real $x$. We use the intermediate value theorem to conclude that $h$ intersects $g$ in each of the $n$  intervals metioned in the previous paragraph, i.e. $g(x)=h(x)$ has $n$ real solutions.

Let $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ be such that $h(x_0)=g(x_0)$. Then, by setting $\theta :=\arccos\frac{x_0}{\sqrt{x_0^2+1}}$, we get:
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(x_0+i)^n+(x_0-i)^n &=(x_0+i)^n+\overline{(x_0+i)^n} \\ \\ &=2\cdot\Re\left((x_0+i)^n\right) \\ \\&=2\cdot\Re\left(e^{in\theta}\left(\sqrt{x_0^2+1}\right)^n\right)\\ \\ &= 2\cos\left(n\theta\right)\left(\sqrt{x_0^2+1}\right)^n\\ \\ &=x_0^n
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$
This implies that the original equation has at least $n$ real solutions. However, since it is a polynomial of degree $n$, it cannot have more than $n$ solutions, which means that all solutions must be real.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much. A very helpful solution.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $p_n:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{C}$ given by
$$
p_n(x)=(1+ix)^n.
$$
The argument
$$
\theta_n(x):=\arg p_n(x)=n\arctan x
$$
then increases from $-n\pi/2$ to $+n\pi/2$ as $x$ increases from $-\infty$ to
$+\infty$.

**Observation #1:** In any interval, where $\theta_n(x)$ either

- increases from $-\pi/2+2k\pi$ to $-\pi/3+2k\pi$ for some integer $k$, or
- increases from $2k\pi+\pi/3$ to $2k\pi+\pi/2$,

there exists an $x$ such that the real part of $p_n(x)=1/2$.

**Proof:** The absolute value $p_n(x)$ is always $\ge1$. So if $[a,b]$ is an interval of one of the above types, then at the end corresponding to an odd multiple of $\pi/2$, the real part of $p_n(x)=0$. At the other end the cosine of the argument is $1/2$ and therefore the real part of $p_n(x)\ge1/2$. The claim follows from continuity.

**Observation #2:** If $p_n(x)$ has real part $=1/2$, then $z=1/x$ is a solution
of the original equation.

**Proof:** If $p_n(x)=1/2+it$, then
$$
(1+ix)^n+(1-ix)^n=p_n(x)+\overline{p_n}(x)=(\frac12+it)+(\frac12-it)=1.
$$
Dividing this by $x^n$ gives
$$
(1/x+i)^n+(1/x-i)^n=(1/x)^n
$$
proving the claim.

The claim follows from these observations, the known codomain of $\theta_n(x)=n\arctan x$, and the fact that $z=0$ is a solution for all odd $n$. If $n=2m$ is even, then there are exactly $2m$ intervals of the type covered in the first observation. OTOH, if $n=2m+1$ then those same $2m$ intervals are included in the range of $\theta_n(x)$, and we have the extra zero from $z=0$.

In either case we have found $n$ real zeros, so there cannot be others.

Comment: Perhaps a bit too similar to the nice solution by SomeStrangeUser. I just thought that going reciprocal and using $1/x$ instead would make the idea more transparent because we can focus on the points where the real part equals $1/2$. You be the judge.