# Sum of complex numbers with different arguments

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Given $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$ with $\arg(z_1)\neq\arg(z_2)$ and $|z_1|=|z_2|$ and given $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Is it necessarily true that $(x+z_1)^n+(x-z_2)^n\notin\mathbb{R}$ for all integer $n\gt0$?

I encountered this hypothesis while trying to formulate a cleaner solution to an [old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2049343/the-solutions-of-z-inzin-zn-are-real/2049652#2049652).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take, for instance, $z_1=1+i$, $z_2=-1+i$, $x$ is *any* real number, and $n$ is *any* natural number, then$$(x+z_1)^n+(x-z_2)^n\in\Bbb R.$$

Comment: Sorry. While this answer does address the original question, I've had to slightly modify it to better reflect my intention. Specifically, $\mathbb{C}$ is now $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What do you think now?

Answer (score 0):

WLOG $z_1=r(\cos p+i\sin p) ;z_2=r(\cos q+i\sin q)$

$$(x+z_1)^n=(x^2+r^2+2rx\cos p)^{n/2}e^{n i\arctan\dfrac{r\sin p}{x+r\cos p}}$$

So, if $f(n)=(x+z_1)^n+(x-z_2)^n$ is real

$$\cos p=-\cos q$$

$$q=2m\pi+\pi\pm p$$

$$f(n)=(x^2+r^2+2rx\cos p)^{n/2}\left(e^{i\arctan\dfrac{r\sin p}{x+r\cos p}}+e^{i\arctan\dfrac{-r\sin(\pi\pm p)}{x-r\cos(\pi\pm p)}}\right)$$

So, we need $$\arctan\dfrac{r\sin p}{x+r\cos p}=-\arctan\dfrac{-r\sin(\pi\pm p)}{x+r\cos p}$$

which is true if $q=2m\pi+\pi-p$

$\implies z_2=r(-\cos p+i\sin p)$